# How can I add an image to the "real place" theme in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes

How can I add an image to the "real place" theme in WordPress?

I thought of adding the following code in functions.php:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/banner.jpg" />
```

`banner.jpg` image is inside media folder in WordPress. How can I add a `banner.jpg` image to the "real place" theme in WordPress? Is it right to add some code inside the function.php file in the "real place" template?